# To read from file and store data in map c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, dictionary, search

I am trying to read file contents and store it in map data structure, where I am trying to skip comment section not be included in my map. I am unable to keep my map as expected, I am kind off clueless how to go ahead. I have mentioned how my map should look like. Please suggest me what changes I have to add in my code. Thanks in Advnc :)

Input file:

```
# Filename: MyFile
# Revision: 107

Items              Types       count     price
snacks             junkfood
Mango              fruit        5         50
strawbery          fruit        10        50
carrot             veggie
burger             junkfood
beetroot           veggie       4         20
cinnamon           masala
```

Expected output file:
Stored in **map<string, string>**
*[key]                 [value]*

```
Items      ->        Types       count     price
snacks     ->        junkfood
Mango      ->        fruit        5         50
strawbery  ->        fruit        10        50
carrot     ->        veggie
burger     ->        junkfood
beetroot   ->        veggie       4         20
cinnamon   ->        masala
```

CPP file:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> attribute_pair;

void check(ifstream &inputFile, map<string, string> &diffm)
{
    diffm.clear();
    std::string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
       std::stringstream ss(line);
       attribute_pair attribute;

       while (ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second)
       {
          if (attribute.first != "#")
               diffm[attribute.first] = attribute.second;
       }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    map<string, string> list1;
     
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        std::ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);
        check(inputFile, list1);

        map<string, string>::iterator itr;
        for (itr = list1.begin(); itr != list1.end(); itr++)
        {
           cout << itr->first << "     " << itr->second << "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage <prog name here> <filename1 here> <filename2 here>\n";
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to do at least three different things with this code. Split the task into smaller tasks, and find out which are working.

Comment: @AK90 But the point is that the single task is too complex for you to handle. That's why you need to subdivide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mistake

```
while (getline(inputFile, line, '\0'))
```

should be

```
while (getline(inputFile, line))
```

The first one reads 'lines' terminated by the `\0` character, which I seriously doubt is what you want. You want lines terminated by the `\n` character, that's what the second version does.

This illustrates the point that Beta was making. The very first thing you try is bugged, so writing and testing the rest of the code is a waste of time. You should write a little piece of code (like checking that you can read a file one line at a time) and only when you are sure that is working should you move onto to the rest of your task. For instance, after working out how to read the file one line at a time, the next task should be to see if you can skip the comment lines. See? Break the task into smaller tasks **and solve each smaller task before moving onto the next**. That is vitally important. Solving doesn't just mean writing and compiling the code, it means writing the code **and** writing some code to check that it is working (like some `std::cout << ...` code).

Always make baby steps (especially when you are learning). There's too many things that can go wrong for you to write 20 lines of code at once. Write two, three, or four lines of code, test that code and only when it is working write some more code.

Comment: still my map doesn't contain the expected result with that change

Comment: @AK90 Of course because you have many other bugs, you are approaching this in the wrong way, you have bugs on top of bugs, which is a impossible situation to be in, you are just guessing at problems, and any change you make is as likely to make things worse as better. See my updated answer for the correct approach.

Comment: @AK90 Another thing to consider, you are testing the attributes for the `#` character. Seems to me that you should be testing the **line** for the `#` character, and if the line starts with `#` don't bother to read any attributes.

Comment: @AK90 One final point. Your code reads pairs of strings, but your input file is **not** structured that way. There is an initial string which you want to be the key of your map, then a succession of strings which you want to be the values. So the approach of reading pairs is not going to work. For each line you need to read the first string, and then have a loop reading each subsequent string. That approach reflects the format of your file

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling generous, I am guessing somewhat at your requirements (particularly how the value part of the map is meant to be). I have not tested this code.

```
void check(ifstream &inputFile, map<string, string> &diffm)
{
    diffm.clear();
    std::string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
       if (line.empty() || line[0] == '#')
       {
           // skip blank or comment lines
       }
       else
       {
           std::stringstream ss(line);
           std::string key, value;
           // read first string (key)
           ss >> key;
           // read rest of line (value)
           getline(ss, value);
           diffm[key] = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. for solutions and guidelines..